# Setting absolute path in ajax not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to set the absolute path to the url so that it loads from domain.com/functions/contact.php, but when I do so I get a 500 server status error

```
$.ajax({
        url: "/functions/contact.php",
        type: "post",
        data: {stage : optionScope.data().stage,
              topics: optionScope.data().topic,
              mentor: optionScope.data().mentor,
              fname: $('#fname').val(),
              email: $('#email').val(),
              humancheck: $('#humancheck').val()
            },
        success: function (response) {
            console.log("data sent successfully");
            window.location = response;

        },
        error: function (xhr, desc, err) {
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log("Details: " + desc + "\nError:" + err);
        }
    });
```

Comment: a 500 error means that there is a problem on your server. a 404 would indicate a problem w/ the url.

Comment: data is being post to the function which then sends an email and then redirect

Comment: the specific error i am getting is Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: in the php set `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` and in the ajax success function add `console.log(response)` then you'll see the php error in the console

Comment: thanks it says Warning: require(/vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/app/current/functions/contact.php on line 5

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/pear:/usr/share/php') in /var/app/current/functions/contact.php on line 5

Comment: ok, so you just need to figure out why it can't find those files and you should be good to go

Comment: alright i just need to set the absolute path of require("vendor/autoload") since the url have been rewritten and require("/vendor/autoload") does not work